# Extract string between parenthesis in R

Tags: regex, r

I have to extract values between a very peculiar feature in R. For eg.

```
 a <- "{1:0987617820}{2:q312132498s7yd09f8sydf987s6df8797yds9f87098}
{3:{112:123123214321}}{4:20:asdasd3214213}"
```

This is my example string and I wish to extract text between {[0-9]: and } such that my output for the above string looks like

```
## output should be 
"0987617820" "q312132498s7yd09f8sydf987s6df8797yds9f87098", "{112:123123214321}" "20:asdasd3214213"
```

Comment: Looks almost like JSON, maybe the "rjson" package would help you?

Comment: It will be difficult to do this with regex because you have a nested structure.

Comment: Exactly the nested structure is adding to the problem.

Comment: The data that I have is an extract that I have received in excel format so I do not have the JSON files/extracts with me. I am importing this in R from a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PERL. This way is a bit more robust.

```
a = "{1:0987617820}{2:q312132498s7yd09f8sydf987s6df8797yds9f87098}{3:{112:123123214321}}{4:20:asdasd3214213}"

foohacky = function(str){
    #remove opening bracket
    pt1 = gsub('\\{+[0-9]:', '@@',str)
    #remove a closing bracket that is preceded by any alphanumeric character
    pt2 = gsub('([0-9a-zA-Z])(\\})', '\\1',pt1, perl=TRUE) 
    #split up and hack together the result
    pt3 = strsplit(pt2, "@@")[[1]][-1]
    pt3
}
```

For example

```
> foohacky(a)
[1] "0987617820"                                 
[2] "q312132498s7yd09f8sydf987s6df8797yds9f87098"
[3] "{112:123123214321}"                         
[4] "20:asdasd3214213"
```

It also works with nesting

```
> a = "{1:0987617820}{{3:{112:123123214321}}{4:{20:asdasd3214213}}"
> foohacky(a)
[1] "0987617820"         "{112:123123214321}" "{20:asdasd3214213}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a horrible hack and probably breaks on your real data.  Ideally you could just use a parser but if you're stuck with regex... well... it's not pretty

```
a <- "{1:0987617820}{2:q312132498s7yd09f8sydf987s6df8797yds9f87098}
{3:{112:123123214321}}{4:20:asdasd3214213}"

# split based on }{ allowing for newlines and spaces
out <- strsplit(a, "\\}[[:space:]]*\\{")
# Make a single vector
out <- unlist(out)
# Have an excess open bracket in first
out[1] <- substring(out[1], 2)
# Have an excess closing bracket in last
n <- length(out)
out[length(out)] <-  substring(out[n], 1, nchar(out[n])-1)
# Remove the number colon at the beginning of the string
answer <- gsub("^[0-9]*\\:", "", out)
```

which gives

```
> answer
[1] "0987617820"                                 
[2] "q312132498s7yd09f8sydf987s6df8797yds9f87098"
[3] "{112:123123214321}"                         
[4] "20:asdasd3214213"
```

You could wrap something like that in a function if you need to do this for multiple strings.

Comment: Note that this breaks if you have multiple items nested in a single item though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more general way, which returns any pattern between `{[0-9]:` and `}` allowing for a single nest of `{}` inside the match.

```
regPattern <- gregexpr("(?<=\\{[0-9]\\:)(\\{.*\\}|.*?)(?=\\})", a, perl=TRUE)
a_parse <- regmatches(a, regPattern)
a <- unlist(a_parse)
```